# Can't delete Django (permission denied)

Tags: django, macos, terminal, permissions

How to delete Django framework after install?

used this way in terminal:

1. `tar xzvf Django-1.8.4`
2. `cd Django-1.8.4`
3. `sudo python setup.py install`

When i am trying to delete folder (site-packages) with files, i get an answer: permission denied

Comment: What command are you using to delete the folder. You probably need to use `sudo` and the `-r` option to delete recursively. Be careful to delete the correct directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you installed setup.py with "sudo", you installed django as the root user. You may not be able to delete files generated with this script unless you run the delete command as root.

Try "sudo rm -r site-packages".

In the future, why not install packages with "python setup.py install" instead of "sudo python setup.py install".

Comment: thanks a lot. Maybe you know, have i any ways to install django in another folder that it was?

Answer (score 0):

You need to run "sudo rm -rf site-packages" and remember not to tinker with your python installation. If you end up messing the python installation, then, you will have to re-install the whole OS X! Just, try not to do multiple deletes and installs.